# How can send PDF attachment in `Node aws-sdk` sendRawEmail function?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, email-attachments, amazon-ses

I want to send a PDF file in an attachment using the `sendRawEmail(Node: aws-sdk)` function. I have tried lots of ways. The email is send successfully, but the PDF goes plain.

How can my code be corrected?

The code is here:

```
try {
    data = fs.readFileSync('files/demo-invoice-new.pdf', 'utf8');

    console.log(data.toString());

    var ses_mail = "From: 'AWS SES Attchament Configuration' <" + SOURCE_EMAIL + ">\n";
    ses_mail = ses_mail + "To: " + toEmail + "\n";
    ses_mail = ses_mail + "Subject: AWS SES Attachment Example\n";
    ses_mail = ses_mail + "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    ses_mail = ses_mail + "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"NextPart\"\n\n";
    ses_mail = ses_mail + "--NextPart\n";
    ses_mail = ses_mail + "Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii\n\n";
    ses_mail = ses_mail + "This is the body of the email.\n\n";
    ses_mail = ses_mail + "--NextPart\n";
    ses_mail = ses_mail + "Content-Type: application/octet;\n";
    ses_mail = ses_mail + "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"demo-invoice-new.pdf\"\n\n";
    ses_mail = ses_mail + data.toString('utf8') + "\n\n";
    ses_mail = ses_mail + "--NextPart--";

    var params = {
        RawMessage: { Data: new Buffer(ses_mail) },
        Destinations: [toEmail],
        Source: "'AWS SES Attchament Configuration' <" + SOURCE_EMAIL + ">'"
    };

    console.log(params);

    var sendPromise = new AWS.SES(AWS_SES_CONFIG).sendRawEmail(params).promise();

    return sendPromise.then(
        data => {
            console.log(data);
            return data;
        }).catch(
        err => {
            console.error(err.message);
            throw err;
        });
} catch (e) {
    console.log('Error:', e.stack);
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

SES raw messages [must be base64-encoded](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_SendRawEmail.html). So, you'll need to get the file content as buffer and encode it as Base64 string attachment. Also, you don't need to create a new buffer for raw message data since it already accepts a string data type.

***Optional***: You can also omit the `Destinations` parameter since you're already providing the `To` field in the raw message data. (You can also provide the `Cc` and `Bcc` fields as well.)

You could try this for example:

```
data = fs.readFileSync("files/demo-invoice-new.pdf");

var ses_mail = "From: 'AWS SES Attchament Configuration' <" + SOURCE_EMAIL + ">\n";
ses_mail += "To: " + toEmail + "\n";
ses_mail += "Subject: AWS SES Attachment Example\n";
ses_mail += "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
ses_mail += "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"NextPart\"\n\n";
ses_mail += "--NextPart\n";
ses_mail += "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";
ses_mail += "This is the body of the email.\n\n";
ses_mail += "--NextPart\n";
ses_mail += "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"demo-invoice-new.pdf\"\n";
ses_mail += "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
ses_mail += "Content-Disposition: attachment\n\n";
ses_mail += data.toString("base64").replace(/([^\0]{76})/g, "$1\n") + "\n\n";
ses_mail += "--NextPart--";

var params = {
    RawMessage: {Data: ses_mail},
    Source: "'AWS SES Attchament Configuration' <" + SOURCE_EMAIL + ">'"
};
```

***Note***: The `/([^\0]{76})/` regular expression replacement breaks your long lines to make sure that mail servers do not complain about message lines being too long when there is an encoded attachment, which might result in a transient bounce (see [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.5.3.1.6)).

Comment: If omitting the Destinations parameter to AWS API request, it would respond with a 400 Bad request error. I would say that this parameter can be empty, since the To, Cc and Bcc email addresses are provided.

Answer (score 8):

I managed to solve it using [nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/) and [SESV2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SESV2.html#sendEmail-property). I had [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded data, so your script might be a little different from mine, but the snippet below should give you an idea... Here's my solution:

```js
const MailComposer = require("nodemailer/lib/mail-composer");
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

const generateRawMailData = (message) => {
    let mailOptions = {
        from: message.fromEmail,
        to: message.to,
        subject: message.subject,
        text: message.bodyTxt,
        html: message.bodyHtml,
        attachments: message.attachments.map(a => ({ filename: a.name, content: a.data, encoding: 'base64' }))
    };
    return new MailComposer(mailOptions).compile().build();
};

const exampleSendEmail = async () => {
    var message = {
        fromEmail: "sender@server.com",
        to: "receiver@sender.com",
        subject: "Message title",
        bodyTxt: "Plaintext version of the message",
        bodyHtml: "<p>HTML version of the message</p>",
        attachments: [{
            name: 'hello.txt',
            data: 'aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ='
        }]
    };

    let ses = new AWS.SESV2(),
    params = {
      Content: { Raw: { Data: await generateRawMailData(message) } },
      Destination: {
        ToAddresses: message.to,
        BccAddresses: message.bcc,
      },
      FromEmailAddress: message.fromEmail,
      ReplyToAddresses: message.replyTo,
    };

  return ses.sendEmail(params).promise();
}
```

Comment: MailComposer is now deprecated. https://github.com/nodemailer/mailcomposer.
Replacement - https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer

Comment: Is there a way using only AWS SES api?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that, the data you have retrieved from your file is not correct or the reading is not good.

I have tried it, and it works the only change i made was the type of data.
Instead of reading a file, i gave the html (mjml) data i wanted to be printed as pdf